# How to define a foreign key using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to define a foreign key using mongoose in nodeJS?

Here is an example of schema that I'm trying to make, where `id_def` needs to refer to the primary key of `def` table which is `id`

```
var abcSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    id_def: Number // foreign key
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var abcSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    _def: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'def' }
});
```

Comment: If you wanted a many to many relationship you would have to do the same thing in the "def" Schema. You would have to add something like: `_abc: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'abc' }`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var abcSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    desc: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'desc'
    }
});
```